# How to handle similar but different apostrophe from input

Tags: android, unicode

I have an EditText that functions as a search box. The user enters a name of a movie he wants to see, and the result comes from the server.

In the server there is a movie named: Michael's Secret - **notice the apostrophe**.

if the user enters "[regular](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2019&B1=Show)" (unicode code U+2019) apostrophe then the server successfully finds this movie. But he might chose from the keyboard similar characters like  [U+0027](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0027) or [U+FF07](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=FF07), and then the movie isn't found.

How can I behave to all the similar apostrophes the same way? meaning, although the user entered U+FF07, a movie name with U+2019 will be found?

Comment: Please post your code the way you passing to server